# Php PhpZip error Unexpected end of archive

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

Am trying to secure files with password before downloading it, but it showing error.
Am using `PhpZip`

Password Secure Archive

```
$zipFile = new \PhpZip\ZipFile();
$zipFile->addFile(__DIR__ . "/../files/oneTextFile.txt");
// Or $zipFile->addFile(__DIR__ . "/../files/oneZipFile.zip");
$zipFile->setPassword("12345Abc");
$zipFile->saveAsFile("secure-file.zip");
$zipFile->close();
```

Download Code

```
$file = __DIR__ . "/downloads/secure-file.zip";
if(file_exists($file)){
    $type = mime_content_type($file);
    if(!empty($type)){
        header("Content-Type: {$type}");
    }else{
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    }
    //header('Content-Type: package/x-generic');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Cache-Control: private");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    unlink($file);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: First, confirm if the zip file is valid by downloading through a trusted binary method such as FTP. If invalid, fix the zipper, if valid, fix the downloaded. If the latter, run a binary diff between the manually downloaded zip and this version. Look for error messages or warnings in clear text specifically.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I tried your guide and it happen to be during download that the file corrupt. Please any better way to download without issue?

Comment: Did you diff the two files and find an error or warning message?